# Choosing a random element from a list of tuples C#

Tags: c#, winforms, random, tuples

I'm quite new to programming and I am trying to add a random bot move to a small game I've made. My idea was to make a list of tuples of all of the legal moves and then pick a random tuple from that list to then deconstruct and change a value in a 2D-array.
I've looked all over the internet and found a way to make a list of tuples (I think), but couldn't manage to pick a random element from that list.

This is what I tried:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> legalMoves; // To make the list of tuples

// Later on in a double for-loop that iterates through all the rows and columns of the 2D-array I check if that certain row and column combination is a legal move and then add it to the list like so:

legalMoves.Add(Tuple.Create(row, col));

//Then in a different method I try to pick a random element from that list (this doesn't work)

Random random = new Random();
int randomIndex = random.Next(legalMoves.Count);
(int, int) randomMove = legalMoves[randomIndex];
```

It gives the following error on the last line:
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<int, int>' to '(int, int)'

Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The correct type is ValueTuple, not Tuple

Comment: If you have doubts, declared it as `var randomMove = legalMoves[randomIndex];` and see what Type is inferred

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] to make your future questions better - i.e. there is absolutely nothing about random numbers related to the question you asking -  `(int, int) randomMove = Tuple.Create(1,2);` is all the code necessary to ask this question... (which also would get chance to provide a better title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `(int, int)` defines a `ValueTuple<int,int>` not a `Tuple<int,int>`. Change the list definition to :

```
List<ValueTuple<int, int>> legalMoves;
```

and `Tuple.Create` to `ValueTuple.Create`

Comment: This seemed to fix my initial problem, but when I tried to run it it gave me the following error at the place where it is adding the legal moves to the list of tuples:
'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @Jasper did you initialize the `List<>` ?

Comment: Thank you very much it is all fixed now!